# Is this proof right? If $a, b \in \mathbb{R}_+$ such that $a \neq b$ show that $\sqrt{ab} < (a+b)/2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

If $a, b \in \mathbb{R}_+$ such that $a \neq b$ show that $\sqrt{ab} < \frac{a+b}{2}$

Here is my attempt:

*Proof:* Suppose that $\sqrt{ab} \geq \frac{a+b}{2}$ , since both sides of the inequality are positive, it follows that: $4ab \geq a^2 +2ab + b^2 \Rightarrow (a-b)^2 \leq 0$, note that the expression $(a-b)^2<0$ does not make sense, then $(a-b)^2=0$ so that $a=b$ which contradicts the hypotesis. Therefore $\sqrt{ab} < \frac{a+b}{2}$.

My only concern is whether it is correct to square an inequality in which both sides are positive.

Comment: I just discovered this is a duplicate question.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ is an increasing function of $x$ when $x>0$, as is $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ so yes you can square or square-root both sides of an inequality when both are non-negative.  But you do not need to aim for a contradiction here.  $(a-b)^2>0 \implies a^2+2ab+b^2>4ab$ will get you the result you want

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to argue by contradiction.  Expand this:
$$0\le \left(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}\right)^2.$$
This will give you a direct proof.

Comment: Typo alert, think it should $\cdots \sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b} \cdots $

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct but you don't need to use contradiction. Instead, argue that

$$\sqrt{ab}< \sqrt{ab}+\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}-\sqrt{\frac{b}{2}}\right)^2=\frac{a+b}{2}$$

The strict inequality follows since $a\neq b$.